# Meaning of "rah-rah rally"

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

Am I right that a *rah-rah rally* is principally a rally held to (uncritically and enthusiastically) celebrate someone or something or are there connotations I'm not aware of?

Is this spoken /rɑːrɑː ˈræli/? I could neither find an English definition nor a phonetic transcription.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From NOAD:

> **rah** (*exclamation*) a cheer of encouragement or approval
>          ORIGIN late 19th cent.: shortening of *hurrah*.

I don’t know of anyone who actually yells “rah” spontaneously at a sporting event, but you sometimes might hear it repeated in a scripted cheer:

> Rah! Rah! Ski-U-Mah. Rah! Rah! Rah!
>   March on, March on to Victory
>   Loyal Sons of Varsity
>   Fight on, Fight on for Minnesota
>   For the glory of the Old Maroon and Gold
>
> Source: [Minnesota March](https://soundcloud.com/mnmarch/minnesota-march)

Your hunch about the meaning of *rah-rah rally* is spot on. A rah-rah rally is packed with supporters who are more interested in whipping up excitement for a person or idea than carefully analyzing it or debating it.